# redirect errot - NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'edit' with keyword arguments '{'title': 'Python'}' not found

Tags: python, django, redirect

I'm working on an app that allows the user to create, show and edit an entry. right now i'm working on the editing function. what i'm trying to do is have an edit button (that's actually a form that sends data via hidden inputs) that sends the title of the entry to a view called trans whose sole purpose is redirect to the edit view, the reason i did this is so that when i'm working on the edit view, i can simplify the process where if the request method is GET it shows the page with the form where the user can edit the entry and if it's post the edit view can receive the changes and save them without worrying about the redirecting from the entry's page.

The problem lies in the fact that everytime i click the edit button i get the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /wiki/trans
Reverse for 'edit' with keyword arguments '{'title': 'Python'}' not found.
```

I have checked over and over for any misspellings or issues in urls.py or any problems with the naming but i just can't find the bug. and it's frustrating because i thought that this would be the easiest part of the project.

Below is the relevant code. i would be extremely grateful for anyone who points out what i'm doing wrong. Thank you in Advance.

**HTML**

```
<div id="edit">
    <form action="{% url 'wiki:trans' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type=hidden value={{title}} name="title">
        <input type=submit value="Edit">
    </form>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
class EntryForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Title")
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

def trans(request):
    title = request.POST.get("title")
    return redirect("wiki:edit", title=title)

def edit(request, title):
    if request.method == "GET":
        entry = util.get_entry(title)

        return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
            "form": EntryForm({
                "content": entry,
                "title": title
            })
        })
    else:
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            content = form.cleaned_data["content"]

        util.save_entry(title, content)
        return redirect("wiki:title", title=title)
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = "wiki"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("new", views.new, name="new"),
    path("trans", views.trans, name="trans"),
    path("edit", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("random", views.rand, name="random"),
    path("<str:title>", views.title, name="title")
]
```

Comment: What does your root `urls.py` look like?

Comment: It's caused by this line: `return redirect("wiki:edit", title=title)` in `trans` view. You are passing a title kwarg for `wiki:edit`, but in your `urls.py`, it's not expecting to receive any kwargs

Comment: The app is called encyclopedia so the path is in a list called urlpatterns. `path('wiki/', include("encyclopedia.urls))`

Comment: There's only one app in the project (this one) and the other view functions work just fine. How is the root urls.py relevant?

Comment: I think the only relevant thing is how you defined `wiki:edit` and how you are using it in this line: `redirect("wiki:edit", title=title)`

Comment: @bdbd thank you for your response. Would you mind showing me how it will look post edit?

Comment: You probably want it to be a query param, so something like: `redirect(f'{reverse("wiki:edit")}?title={title}')`

Comment: Just noticed that your `edit` view accepts a `title` kwarg. Maybe change your url to accept that? like `"edit/<str:title>"`

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a `/` at the end of each url, like this:

`urls.py`:

```
app_name = "wiki"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="search"),
    path("new/", views.new, name="new"),
    path("trans/", views.trans, name="trans"),
    path("edit/", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("random/", views.rand, name="random"),
    path("<str:title>/", views.title, name="title")
]
```

Also try using reverse and passing in the title as an arg on your `views.py`:

```
    return redirect(reverse('wiki:title', args=[title]))
```