# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'edit' with keyword arguments '{'title': ''}' not found

Tags: python, django

This is the extention of the same problem i asked about in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462722/redirect-errot-noreversematch-reverse-for-edit-with-keyword-arguments-ti).

The problem i'm having here now is that after fixing the problem with the trans views function and expecting the program to run without problems, i get the following error

```
NoReverseMatch at /wiki/Python/edit

Reverse for 'edit' with keyword arguments '{'title': ''}' not found.
```

Which i can't for the life of me understand considering that i **AM** passing the title argument in the html and set up the edit views function and the urlpath in urls.py to expect the title argument.

when i take a closer look at the traceback, it highlights this block of code from the edit views function.

```
return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
    "form": EntryForm(initial={
        "title": title,
        "content": entry
    })
})
```

[image]

but i don't understand what the problem is here?

this is the final part of the project i'm working on so i'll be very grateful for any and all help.

below is the relevant code.

**HTML**

*entry.html*

```
<!-- The edit button in the entry's page -->
<form action="{% url 'wiki:trans' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type=hidden value={{title}} name="title">
    <input type=submit value="Edit">
</form>
```

*edit.html*

```
<!-- the edit page -->
{% block body %} 
<h1>Edit Entry</h1>
<br>
<form action="{% url 'wiki:edit' title=title %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="save">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**view.py**

```
class EntryForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Title")
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

def trans(request):
    title = request.POST.get("title")
    return redirect("wiki:edit", title=title)

def edit(request, title):
    if request.method == "GET":
        entry = util.get_entry(title)

        return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
            "form": EntryForm(initial={
                "title": title,
                "content": entry
            })
        })
    else:
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            content = form.cleaned_data["content"]

        util.save_entry(title, content)
        return redirect("wiki:title", title=title)
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = "wiki"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("new", views.new, name="new"),
    path("trans", views.trans, name="trans"),
    path("<str:title>/edit", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("random", views.rand, name="random"),
    path("<str:title>", views.title, name="title")
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [redirect errot - NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'edit' with keyword arguments '{'title': 'Python'}' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462722/redirect-errot-noreversematch-reverse-for-edit-with-keyword-arguments-ti)

Answer (score 1):

```
def edit(request, title):
    if request.method == "GET":
        entry = util.get_entry(title)

        return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
            "form": EntryForm(initial={
                "title": title,
                "content": entry
            })
        })
```

That `render()` call is not passing a value for `title`, therefore the template tries to use a blank value, which is not allowed.

Comment: I think you can change a little bit the parameter with a default value and it will fix the bug... Take a look of my answer.

Comment: But why is it not passing a value? I passed title to the edit function when i redirected from the trans function. And now I'm just trying to pass it to the form using `render()`. Passing title is crucial for the task at hand.

Comment: @sunflower.saturn The only item being passed to the template is `form`.  I see that the form has a field named `title`, but the template expects the title to be a separate element on its own, not part of the form.

Answer (score 0):

The `title` var that you are passing to `title=title` dict is empty that means that the title variable has no data. To fix it make sure that title has a value or change that as optional argument in the url patterns.

You can fix it doing the following:

```
def edit(request, title=None):
```

Then title will take a default value if you don't pass it.

Comment: Passing title is absolutely crucial so i can't replace it with `None`. What i don't understand is why title is empty.

Comment: Then you have to update your question because you know that is the title is empty and that's the whole problem, try to structure your question in a different way so that you can figure out way that variable is empty.